# openCV - imwrite

Tags: opencv

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all!

I like to use the imwrite method from opencv to create a bitmap from a matrix.

http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html?highlight=imwrite#bool%20imwrite%28const%20string&%20filename,%20InputArray%20img,%20const%20vector%3Cint%3E&%20params%29

Which package from openCV I have to import in my python file so that I can use "imwrite"?
I think opencv2? But how can I use this by ROS electric?
Because when I import opencv2 in my python file, I get the message that there is no modul like this.

Thanks for help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51233/opencv---imwrite/) by [JaRu](https://answers.ros.org/users/3620/jaru/) on ROS Answers with karma: 153 on 2012-12-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) on 2012-12-31**:
What exactly are you trying to do with ROS? If this is an opencv question, then suggest you post on the [opencv answer forum](http://answers.opencv.org/questions/). If this is a ROS question, then maybe more info on your problem will help. Otherwise @dinamex answer is probably correct.

**Comment by [JaRu](https://answers.ros.org/users/3620/jaru/) on 2013-01-03**:
I created a data array for the footstep_planner and I like to make a bitmap file from this data array. I know that I could do this with the imwrite method from opencv, but I could not import the opencv methods in my python file. I do not think that I have to use the opencv bridge, I have no image.

**Comment by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) on 2013-01-03**:
Ok ... this is an opencv question and not a ROS question. I use c++ not python, but if you include opencv2 that would give you access to imwrite in c++. However you do that in python should work too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should consider to use [opencv_bridge](http://www.ros.org/wiki/cv_bridge/Tutorials/UsingCvBridgeToConvertBetweenROSImagesAndOpenCVImages)

---

Originally posted by [dinamex](https://answers.ros.org/users/1383/dinamex/) with karma: 447 on 2012-12-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0